# Spring boot application not able to access rest path

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to set up the rules for spring boot to allow/deny access for specific paths. I looked up various examples and stack overflow question, but none was helpful. I created the configuration file as follows:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.window.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${admin.console.username:admin}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${admin.console.password:admin}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(username)
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password)).roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/assets/**", "/api/order/calculate", "/api/order/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/orders.html")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I can access the "/" without a problem. The page is loaded and show with the help of the MVC controller. But the paths that I defined as REST end points, I am not able to access them. I keep getting a 403 response:

> {"timestamp":"2018-10-08T19:22:04.963+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/api/order/calculate"}

What is wrong with my configuration? As you can see from the class, I even went one further and specifically set the calculate end point as oppose to having the ** to include all subpaths.

Comment: /api/order/calculate is POST or GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "/" is working and "/api/order/calculate" is not, it means that they have different HTTP verbs.

```
"/" - is a GET request
"/api/order/calculate" - is a POST request
```

By default, spring security will enable csrf protection (only for POST because GET is considered safe). If you are getting 403, it means that you are not sending csrf header => your access is forbidden.

You said that this is a REST endpoint, so you should disable csrf for this endpoints. To do that, please update your configuration with:

1.disable csrf in general (not recommended if you have web forms)

```
http.csrf()
     .disable();
```

2.if you need to ignore csrf only for specific endpoints, you can add:

```
http.csrf()
    .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/order/calculate")
```